# error :2678, Compilation error in vs 2010,

Tags: visual-c++

```
>c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\algorithm(4494): error C2678:    
binary '=' : no operator found which takes a left-hand operand of type 'const 
std::basic_string<_Elem,_Traits,_Ax>' (or there is no acceptable conversion)
          with
          [
              _Elem=char,
              _Traits=std::char_traits<char>,
           _Ax=std::allocator<char>
          ]
        c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\xstring(707): could be  
'std::basic_string<_Elem,_Traits,_Ax> &std::basic_string<_Elem,_Traits,_Ax>::operator = 
(std::basic_string<_Elem,_Traits,_Ax> &&)'
    with
      [
          _Elem=char,
          _Traits=std::char_traits<char>,
          _Ax=std::allocator<char>
      ]
      c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\xstring(762): or       'std::basic_string<_Elem,_Traits,_Ax> &std::basic_string<_Elem,_Traits,_Ax>::operator =(const std::basic_string<_Elem,_Traits,_Ax> &)'
      with
      [
          _Elem=char,
          _Traits=std::char_traits<char>,
          _Ax=std::allocator<char>
      ]
      c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\xstring(767): or       
'std::basic_string<_Elem,_Traits,_Ax> &std::basic_string<_Elem,_Traits,_Ax>::operator =  
(const _Elem *)'
    with
      [
          _Elem=char,
          _Traits=std::char_traits<char>,
          _Ax=std::allocator<char>
      ]
      c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\xstring(772): or         
'std::basic_string<_Elem,_Traits,_Ax> &std::basic_string<_Elem,_Traits,_Ax>::operator =  
(_Elem)'
    with
   [
          _Elem=char,
          _Traits=std::char_traits<char>,
          _Ax=std::allocator<char>
       ]
      while trying to match the argument list '(const  
std::basic_string<_Elem,_Traits,_Ax>, const std::basic_string<_Elem,_Traits,_Ax>)'
      with
      [
          _Elem=char,
          _Traits=std::char_traits<char>,
          _Ax=std::allocator<char>
      ]
      c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\algorithm(4522) : see   
reference to function template instantiation '_OutIt  
std::_Set_intersection<_InIt1,_InIt2,_OutIt>(_InIt1,_InIt1,_InIt2,_InIt2,_OutIt)' being  
compiled
      with
      [


_OutIt=std::_Tree_const_iterator<std::_Tree_val<std::_Tset_traits<std::string,std::less<std    ::string>,std::allocator<std::string>,false>>>,


_InIt1=std::_Tree_unchecked_const_iterator<std::_Tree_val<std::_Tset_traits<std::string,std::less<std::string>,std::allocator<std::string>,false>>>,


_InIt2=std::_Tree_unchecked_const_iterator<std::_Tree_val<std::_Tset_traits<std::string,std ::less<std::string>,std::allocator<std::string>,false>>>
      ]
      c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\algorithm(4549) : see  
reference to function template instantiation '_OutIt  
std::_Set_intersection1<std::_Tree_unchecked_const_iterator<_Mytree>,std::_Tree_unchecked_
const_iterator<_Mytree>,_OutIt> 
(_InIt1,_InIt1,_InIt2,_InIt2,_OutIt,std::tr1::true_type)' being compiled
      with
      [



_OutIt=std::_Tree_const_iterator<std::_Tree_val<std::_Tset_traits<std::string,std::less<std      ::string>,std::allocator<std::string>,false>>>,


_Mytree=std::_Tree_val<std::_Tset_traits<std::string,std::less<std::string>,std::allocator< 
std::string>,false>>,


_InIt1=std::_Tree_unchecked_const_iterator<std::_Tree_val<std::_Tset_traits<std::string,std
::less<std::string>,std::allocator<std::string>,false>>>,

_InIt2=std::_Tree_unchecked_const_iterator<std::_Tree_val<std::_Tset_traits<std::string,std     ::less<std::string>,std::allocator<std::string>,false>>>
         ]
     c:\qc\qc_daq_development\qc\qc_daq\src\hfgui3\expscan.cpp(458) : see reference to  
function template instantiation '_OutIt 

std::set_intersection<std::_Tree_const_iterator<_Mytree>,std::_Tree_const_iterator<_Mytree>     ,std::_Tree_const_iterator<_Mytree>>(_InIt1,_InIt1,_InIt2,_InIt2,_OutIt)' being   
compiled
      with
      [


_OutIt=std::_Tree_const_iterator<std::_Tree_val<std::_Tset_traits<std::string,std::less<std 
::string>,std::allocator<std::string>,false>>>,


_Mytree=std::_Tree_val<std::_Tset_traits<std::string,std::less<std::string>,std::allocator<
std::string>,false>>,


_InIt1=std::_Tree_const_iterator<std::_Tree_val<std::_Tset_traits<std::string,std::less<std
::string>,std::allocator<std::string>,false>>>,


_InIt2=std::_Tree_const_iterator<std::_Tree_val<std::_Tset_traits<std::string,std::less<std
::string>,std::allocator<std::string>,false>>>
```

Above mentioned is the error message thrown while compiling the a program with visual studio 2010, as it works well in visual studio 2003, so i am really unable to figure out the problem!!! any help or suggestion will be deeply appreciated!!! Thanks in advance.

I am pasting the line which is throwing the above error msg.
In case if someone more information, please let me know, i will be grateful to you if you spend your precious time in helping me to fix it. 
Many thanks in advance

```
SET_STR::iterator itOut =  
std::set_intersection(setType.begin(),setType.end(),setCategory.begin(),setCategory.end(),s
etFilter.begin());
setFilter.erase(itOut,setFilter.end()); //erase the rest of the set
```

Definations:

```
 typedef std::set<string>                   SET_STR;
 typedef std::map<string, SET_STR >         MAP_STR_SETSTR;
 typedef std::map<char, SET_STR >           MAP_CHAR_SETSTR;
 typedef std::map<string,SfvarInfo>         MAP_STR_FVARINFO;


CritSec                 m_csVarAccess;                  
MAP_STR_VAL             m_mapVar;
MAP_STR_VAL             m_mapFvarOverrides;
MAP_STR_VAL             m_mapFvarOrig;
MAP_STR_FVARINFO        m_mapFvarInfo;
MAP_STR_SETSTR          m_mapCategoryFvar;              
MAP_CHAR_SETSTR         m_mapTypeFvar;                  
MAP_STR_VAL             m_mapLoadedFvar;

UserParam<string>       m_sScanFvar;
UserParam<string>       m_sFvarFilterType;
UserParam<string>       m_sFvarFilterCategory;

SET_STR setType(m_mapTypeFvar[m_sFvarFilterType.c_str()[0]]);
SET_STR setCategory(m_mapCategoryFvar[m_sFvarFilterCategory]);
```

Comment: Can you please include definitions for SET_STR, setType, setCategory, setFilter?

Comment: Thanks pragnar please let me know if i miss something!!

Answer (score 3):

You can't assign to the element pointed to by an iterator into a `std::set` because that would change the 'placement' of that element in the set (in the general case). So you can't use `setFilter.begin()` as the output iterator for the `set_intersection()` call, since `set_intersection()` assigns through the iterator.

Basically, `set::iterator` is always a `const_iterator` in VS 2010. I no longer have VS2003 installed, so I can't test, but I'd guess that back then that wasn't the case, so it compiled.

Use a std::insert_iterator<> instead:

```
std::set_intersection( setType.begin(), setType.end(),
                       setCategory.begin(), setCategory.end(), 
                       inserter( setFilter, setFilter.begin()));
```

This will complicate the `erase()` that you're doing after the `set_intersection()` call since `set_intersection()` will now return an `insert_iterator<>` instead of a `set<>::iterator`.From the code you posted, it looks like you want the final contents of `setFilter` to contain only the elements in the intersection, so just make sure `setFilter` is empty when `set_intersection()` is called, and there's no need for the `erase()` operation.

Scott Meyers talks about this kind of thing in "Effective STL", "Item 22: Avoid in-place key modification in `set` and `multiset`", including how some compilers will use `const_iterator`-style iterators for `std::set`.

Comment: thanks micheal, but i am not able to follow your useful suggestion. I am new to vc++, so please help me with possible syntax.

Comment: What error are you getting when you try? Use std::inserter(...) and add the line #include <iterator>

Comment: What pragnar said, plus you'll need to remove the assignment to `SET_STR::iterator itOut` and therefore the `erase()` call as well.